# How to check if vue-meta is adding meta data

Tags: vuejs2, vue-meta

I have some code here, and I want to inspect the page's source code to see if it's working, but I can't see anything in the source code.

```
export default {
    name: 'LandingPage',

    metaInfo() {
        return {
            title: this.page.title,
            meta: [
                {
                    property: 'og:title',
                    content: this.page.title,
                    template: chunk => `${chunk} - Website name`,
                    vmid: 'og:title'
                },
            ],
        };
    },

    ...
}
```

How do I verify what vue-meta is adding? Is there a way to see it in a SPA app?

Answer (score 0):

I found you can inspect the page elements using the browser's Dev Tools area.

1. In Chrome, press F12 to open the Dev Tools pane
2. Click the Elements Tab
3. Click the document `<head></head>` area to expand it
4. Look for your meta tags

[image]